# Finder - Keyboard shortcut to rename file

Tags: macos, finder

In Windows File Explorer, you can rename a selected file by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>. Is there an equivalent shortcut for macOS Finder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The   <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd>  or  <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>  key will activate rename. So will a second click [so long as it's too slow to be recognised as a double-click]
Once changed, Enter, Return, or simply clicking anywhere else will complete the task.

Whilst in edit mode, all the usual text selection routines [combinations of arrow keys, crtl, opt & shift] will work, the same as in TextEdit etc.

If you accidentally activate rename or realise you have typed something you shouldn't, Esc will get you out of jail free.
If you fully completed the task & did actually rename it & confirm, then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>  will undo the change, so long as you didn't do anything else since. Undo has a 'chain' of actions it can undo back in time, but it's a delicate chain & will break if you do too many things.

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Return</kbd> (aka <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on Windows keyboards) on a selected file to begin renaming.

(Found on [How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/270747/the-fastest-ways-to-rename-files-on-macos/) right after posting...)

Comment: Full-size extended keyboards actually have both Return and Enter. For short keyboards, like on laptops, they share duty on a single key.